# Is the default port 80 for web traffic?

Tags: .htaccess

In terms of redirecting visitors, by not including

```
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
```

will I skip over any potential visitors? Or is port 80 the default?

Answer (score 0):

Port 80 is the default for HTTP, 443 for HTTPS.